# Should I use a database to send HTML to the view page?

Tags: php, mysql

In the application I'm working on, I have to deal with the Facebook GRAPH API to build a profile of the user. As not all data is present on Facebook, some of it will need to be manually inputted by the user through forms. Because there are so many different instances of possible value combinations, this is a bit tricky. I have two options, as I see it, one is to use PHP to find what's missing and then retrieve an HTML response from the database which asks the user to input the data via form. This form would be processed using PHP to add the inputted values back into the DB. The second option is to create PHP functions with HTML inside them, like so:

```
   function getEducation () {
        ?>
            Please provide information about your current academic institution:
            <form method="post" action="processor.php">
            School Name: <input type="text" name="school"><br>
            School Type: <select name="type">
            <option value="High School">High School</option>
            <option value="Community College">Community College</option>
            <option value="College">College</option>
            <option value="Graduate School">Graduate School</option><br>
            </select><br>
            Major: <input type="text" name="major"><br>
            Minor: <input type="text" name="minor"><br>
            Degree: <select name="degree">
                    <option value="Associates">Associates</option>
                    <option value="Bachelors">Bachelors</option>
                    <option value="Masters">Masters</option>
                    <option value="JD">J.D</option>
                    <option value="Doctorate">Doctorate</option>
                    </select><br>
            Graduation Date: <input type="text" name="graduation">
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
            </form>
            <?php
    }
```

Both of these options aren't great but I'm not familiar with Smarty or Zend and time is an issue. Any suggestions?

So I tried something like this, per your comment:

```
$array1 = array($user_profile['education']);
$array2 = array($user_profile['education'][0]['school']['name'], $user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'] ? $user_profile['education'][0]['concentration'][0]['name'] : null , $user_profile['education'][0]['year']['name'] ? $user_profile['education'][0]['year']['name'] : null);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

But I get these error messages because these values in array 2 don't exist which is odd because isn't finding what's missing the whole point of array_diff?

Notice: Undefined index: concentration in C:\xampp\htdocs\pathweavr\arraydif.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\xampp\htdocs\pathweavr\arraydif.php on line 65

Answer (score 0):

Why not have an array of all the needed elements, and then an array of what is actually provided by facebook, then use `array_diff` to show the inputs that need to be manually entered, then there is no use of a databases or functions just pure php code.

Comment: The Facebook GRAPH API is pretty complex. It's a long series of multidimensional arrays. Something to consider though...